# how to remove header of lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, lightning-datatable

Does anyone know how to delete the header of lightning datatable,
and how to put data parts only?

I would like to make table like the attached image.
Red cross parts is supposed to be removed.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove `lightning:datatable` header you can apply attribute `hideTableHeader`

For instance:

```
<lightning:datatable keyField="id" hideTableHeader="true" />
```

Comment: This appears to only hide the **data** in the header - but the header row itself is still visible.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement Oleg's answer, you can always check official documentation for lightning base components at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components. For `lightning:datatable` specifically - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/specification. There you will find all available attributes and examples with sample code.